# Пламя, flame, Flamme

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова пламя, англ. flame и нем. Flamme к этимологически однокоренным, по аналогии с **п**ихта -> **F**ichte

Comment: Наш сайт посвящен русскому языку. Обсуждение его в связи с другими языками возможно, только если приведен весь материал, необходимый для работы с последними (их лингвистические законы, переводы иноязычных слов на русский...).